# Как правильно записать код обработку исключения в Elixir

Tags: исключения, try-catch, elixir

Я не давно начал изучать Elixir, и меня интересует, как правильно записать код в Elixir обработку исключений `try/catch`  Пока попытался создать такой пример.

```
z=90
x=0
if x==0||z==0  do
  raise IO.puts "Div Zero" 
else 
  t=x/z
  IO.puts t
end
```

Вот получил такой ответ

```
Erlang/OTP 20.0
 run-project
Div Zero
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :ok.exception/1 is undefined (module :ok is not available)
    :ok.exception([])
    main.exs:4: (file)
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2

exit status 1
```

Меня интересует, а как сделать, что выводилось при исключении только `"Div Zero"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, Вам нужна конструкция `try/rescue`.
Советую почитать документацию по обработке ошибок в Elixir [здесь](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html) или [здесь (на русском)](https://elixirschool.com/ru/lessons/advanced/error-handling/)

```
z = 90
x = 0

try do
  if x == 0 || z == 0 do
    raise "Some error" 
  else 
    t = x / z
    IO.puts t
  end
rescue
  _ -> IO.puts "Div zero"
end
```